# How to create static variable to avoid spawning hundreds of temporary objects?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a custom class for string serialization

```
public string Serialize(BackgroundJobInfo info)
{
    ....
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo),
        null,
        int.MaxValue,
        true,
        true,
        new MongoDbSurrogate()); // MongoDbSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
    serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, info);
    ...
}

public BackgroundJobInfo Deserialize(string info)
{
      try
        {
            ...
            using (var textReader = new StringReader(info))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo));
                return (BackgroundJobInfo)serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
 }
```

Is it good idea to make `serializer` `private static readonly` to avoid spawning hundreds of temporary objects (is it more faster than I did)?

How to do this thread safety? Instances of `DataContractSerializer` class are thread safe except when the instance is used with an implementation of the `IDataContractSurrogate` or `DataContractResolver`.

How to do it in a thread-safe manor, because `IDataContractoSurrogate` is not thread safe?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that these temporary objects are causing any actual performance issues?

Comment: For small objects, the solution is *buffering*. For large objects, the solution is *pooling*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Now when serializing each object (which is quite often) creates a short-lived object-serializer. Then, the garbage collector has to collect it. Therefore, let the one created somewhere in the beginning of the program and currently lives up to its completion. A little less strain on GC

Comment: @JonSkeet And I have large objects

Comment: Yes, but have you actually measured and found performance to be an issue? Premature optimization is typically frowned on. It's best to keep the code small and simple unless you have real performance issues that have been identified and must be addressed.

Comment: however, the object-serializer does not deteriorate from use and maybe its a good practice to create it once in the beginning of the program

Comment: @JonSkeet What would be your advice?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't have any evidence, but my custom Serializer should be optimized as much as possible

Comment: That suggests you have no target at which point you'll know you're done. That's never a good situation to be in for performance work. Just how far are you wililng to go? Hand-optimized IL? Pull requests for the CLR to optimize things more? That would fit with "as much as possible" after all. I suggest the very first thing you should do is measure the impact of creating these serializers... what happens if you reuse the objects in a single-threaded environment, to start with?

Comment: @JonSkeet Rather than often creating short-lived object-serializer and then GC should collect it. We will just create one member and destroy it once. Is it evidence?

Comment: I completely agree with @JonSkeet. You can't optimize for performance if you don't even know whether or not you have a performance impact and how much it is.

Comment: @Jon Skeet How to test a performance issues like that? I never do this before

Comment: Well do you have any benchmarks, to start with? If not, that's the first thing you should do - there's no point in trying to improve performance if you can't even tell whether you're making it better or not...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An alternative to using a static readonly member, would be to use the built in [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) object to cache the `DataContractSerializer`, asking the `MemoryCache` for it each time you want to deal with the serializer. The `MemoryCache` store is thread-safe so you wouldn't have to worry about it.

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
DataContractSerializer serializer = cache["MonogoSerialzier"] as DataContractSerializer;

if (serializer == null)
{
    serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo),
        null,
        int.MaxValue,
        true,
        true,
        new MongoDbSurrogate()); // MongoDbSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate

    // Cache the serializer with an policy that never expires the cache item.
    cache.Set("MonogoSerialzier", serializer, new CacheItemPolicy().AbsoluteExpiration);
}

serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, info);
```

This will fetch it from the default in-memory cache store when needed. If it doesn't exist you can instance a new one and stuff it in the cache store. You can store multiple instances in the cache store, with different caching policies if needed.

Comment: Why would that be better than using a static readonly member, given that it's *hugely* likely that each serializer would be needed?

Comment: Not saying this is better; rather another solution to the problem.

Comment: But why introduce complexity? It's clearly more complex code than a simple field. That complexity requires justification, IMO.

Comment: How is this complicated? When compared to the number of lines you'd have to write to handle locking, the LOC count ends up virtually the same. Comparing to his original example, I've added 3 additional lines. If there are alternatives to adding statics I tend to prefer them, just a personal preference.

Comment: What locking? The OP is asking (as I understand it) whether it's safe just to use the serializers from multiple threads *without* any locking... Just have static readonly fields for them.

Comment: "_How to do this thread safety? Instances of DataContractSerializer class are thread safe except when the instance is used with an implementation of the IDataContractSurrogate or DataContractResolver_" does not sound like explicitly asking how to do it without locking. It sounds to me like he is asking how to do it in a thread-safe manor, because `IDataContractoSurrogate` is _not_ thread safe. Perhaps I am misreading it? It wouldn't be the first time!

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Yes, you are right. And I'm trying to understand what would work more faster: create one private static readonly member and destroy it once or like I did it in my question ?

Comment: The static readonly member would be faster than a MemoryCache, but what if you have multiple instances you want to cache? It sounds like you might have multiple `IDataContractSurrogates`, with the Mongo one being the only one that's not thread safe. If you have multiple you want to cache, then you have to have multiple readonly static members, one for each serializer instance that has it's dedicated surrogate.

Comment: @JonSkeet How to test a performance issue like that? I never do this before

Comment: As an aside, I don't see anything in `MemoryCache` which suggests that when you fetch a value, it can't be used by another thread as well. It doesn't look like it's a connection pool style "borrow and replace" kind of cache, which is what would be required for thread safety. And yes, I *would* be suggesting multiple static fields, one per type, if that's what's required.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks ;) Maybe you have some article about `benchmarks` in your blog about or video on youtube?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the surrogates work, do they mutate the state of the serializer? If so, then yes the memory cache would not protect against that. I was under the assumption that he was trying to protect the serializer member itself from having a value assigned to it from multiple threads. It the issue is protecting the internal state of the serializer, then locking using the `[ThreadStatic]` answer or locking would be the way to go.

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko: No, not really - I have some experience of microbenchmarking, but that probably wouldn't be appropriate here. But do some research and I'm sure you'll find something appropriate. That's what you should do before going any further. You don't even know whether or not you've actually got a problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

One good option would be marking it thread static https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

This way there is one instance per thread so you don't need to worry about cross thread access:

```
[ThreadStatic]
public static DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo),
    null,
    int.MaxValue,
    true,
    true,
    new MongoDbSurrogate());
```

That said the actual cost of creating a single instance and then garbage collecting it will be negligable. So unless you are aiming for ultra high performance I would advice you to leave the code as is.